# Call vue method from laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a blade in my laravel project that is instantiating a vue component, which loads and operates fine. The problem now is that I'm trying to call a method in my vue component from a select box in the blade and it isn't registering.

As you can see below, I have a method call that should log to the console but when I change the select in the blade it doesn't log in the console, no errors either.

What am I doing wrong?

blade.php

```
        <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;" class="col-lg-4">
            <select @change="filterItem" style="border:none; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
                <option>Open</option>
                <option>Closed</option>
                <option>Paused/Waiting on user</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <elastic-search-autocomplete></elastic-search-autocomplete>
        </div>
```

elasticSearchAutocomplete.vue

```
methods: {

  filterItem(){
    console.log('this is coming from the blade');
  },
}
.......
```

Comment: Shouldn't that `<select>` be in your component? And `filterItem` is not the same as `createItem`

Comment: @kerbholz sorry that's a typo, they are both filterItem.....but no, the select doesn't exist in the component, it's in the blade which exists on it's own and is used with other components elsewhere, so this select should be able to control the function as a parent I would think

Comment: @TomN. Make an edit to question with that to allow the rest have the same code in front of their eyes as much as your have.

Comment: @Tpojka It has the edit fix now

Comment: Any console error or output? Can you provide some intentional console output in mounted event?

Comment: Please put your code in some vue.js online editor, eg here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @Tpojka when I change the select box from the blade there is no console error or output at all. I would expect to see the printed message 'this is coming from the blade'. If I emit the call from a select in the vue component it works, but I need to be able to do it from the blade as well

Comment: Try with [syntax](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) `methods: { filterItem: function (event) { console.log('...from the blade') } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call the method since it is outside of your component. 
Here is an example approach you can do this:
elasticSearchAutocomplete.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="filters" v-bind:statusFilter="statusFilter">

        </slot>

        <div>
            //your elastic search component code
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                statusFilter: null
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

blade:

```
<elastic-search-autocomplete>
    <template v-slot:statusFilter="statusFilter">
    <div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;" class="col-lg-4">
            <select v-model="statusFilter" style="border:none; border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
                <option>Open</option>
                <option>Closed</option>
                <option>Paused/Waiting on user</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </template>
</elastic-search-autocomplete>
```

Now they share statusFilter data and you can make your logic in vue component to filter the data.
In case you don't have access to edit elastic-search-autocomplete component you can always wrap it in your own.